# How to get area coordinate in google map api

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a address and i need to area coordinate(longitude and latitude) of that place in Google (recommended) or any map in JavaScript or PHP

[image]

I need list of longitude and latitude of above 4 corner using Google map API.

[Google map link](https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/10+Lionel+Ave,+North+Ryde+NSW+2113,+Australia/@-33.8014977,151.1334378,20z/data=!4m15!1m9!4m8!1m0!1m6!1m2!1s0x6b12a5f12573f439:0x4c011422e016ac6!2s10+Lionel+Ave,+North+Ryde+NSW+2113,+Australia!2m2!1d151.1336946!2d-33.8014656!3m4!1s0x6b12a5f12573f439:0x4c011422e016ac6!8m2!3d-33.8014656!4d151.1336946)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to right click on the map, choose "What's here", take the coordinates from the box that appears

[image: right click]
[image: What's here]

Doing that for your property, that gives me:

```
-33.801421, 151.133470
-33.801580, 151.133691
-33.801364, 151.133919
-33.801328, 151.133804
```

http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/otr0p64h/

Comment: I need it dynamically just give address `10 Lionel Ave, North Ryde NSW 2113, Australia` and get let lng list. I have already done you provide in jsfiddle.